# Recollect shipping rates in onepage checkout

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout

i am developing a shipping extension that provide various options(insurance, exact hour of delivery, etc) to the customer at the checkout page.
The flow is the following:

1. The customer chooses an address.The received prices of the rates
   does not include the extra fee for the available options.
2. At the shipping method section ot the checkout page, the customer
   can choose some option, and when she clicks the button to proceed to
   the payment methods section, the recalculation of the shipping rates
   must be triggered again.

My goal is to trigger the recollecting of shipping rates  in `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveShippingMethod()`.

How can i achive this?
I've tried the steps in the thread(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671787/unset-shipping-and-recalculate-totals-in-magento), but without any luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can recollect the shipping rates using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();
```

But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: This piece of code did the trick :           $shipping = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save().Thank you, Marius!